# I suspect LINQ queries are slow first time, then fast. Could this be due to.NET4 and EF4.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am using MVC3, .NET4 and EF4.1

I have just noticed that queries can be slow the first time round, then speed up significantly there after ie 10x. When I then query on another record, the query slows again, then speeds up when I next query the records. It feels like SQL code, EF code is getting compiled/cached first time round.

I have read that .NET4.5 is hugely better in this area ie "magic" autocompilation... totally wrong words, but offers great speed performance for this issue. Is this correct?

Also should I consider upgrading from EF4.1 to say 5. We are near live, but if I am going to get significant performance benefits then I really need to consider taking the pain now.

So does .NET4.5 offer something here, be it for LINQ or EF?

How beneficial is upgrading to EF5? Is is significantly better?

Obviously there are side effects. I have just discovered that .NET4.5 stores the annotation code out of EF. Still trying to work out how to get my "Compare" annotation to compile.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a fairly easy way to find out the answers to your questions: make a copy of your project, and change out EF to the newest version.

Comment: Thanks Robert... yes indeed, I do need to do this. I guess I was just trying to pick up on anyone's experience. In addition to retrieving data, I am also transforming the data to XHTML using Razor Views, and there are many Views, so I am wondering whether the first hit of a View is causing a JIT compilation, and since I could use about 20 Views then I can now see how this might be a problem. Precompilation is the answer here. So I might also be looking in the wrong place...